# Split and merge 2 columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to have this kind of disposition in pd.DataFrame :
[image]

Comment: `groupby` should do what you want

Comment: What are input/ouput data?

Comment: I mean take that excel picture as input. Could you create a very simple Dataframe with the same structure ? Like two layers of "columns" with the group MALE and FEMALE having two sub-columns NAME and AGE. It's like a multi-index but with columns

Comment: OK, so what are input data? 4 lists + ID ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create DataFrame by constructor with [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
data = [('Mary',20, 'John', 22)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,
                  columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['MALE','FEMALE'],['NAME','AGE']]))
```

Or use `header=[0,1]` if need `MultiIndex` from header in excel file:

```
df = pd.read_excel(file, index_col=[0], header=[0,1])
```

Comment: Perfect, the first answer is what I was looking for. I didn't know multindex could be set as columns. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

for example :
[image]

```
import pandas as pd

dt = pd.read_excel("1.xlsx", header=[0,1])
print(dt.head())
print(dt.columns)
```

output:

```
                  id   male    
  Unnamed: 0_level_1   name age
0                  1   mary  19
1                  2  emily  20
MultiIndex([(  'id', 'Unnamed: 0_level_1'),
            ('male',               'name'),
            ('male',                'age')],
           )
```